# Is it possible to just drag and drop items anywhere when using Android Studio Designer?

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

I'm using Android Design Studio with a wear app for the first time and its a very frustrating experience.

I just want to get a feel for how a ui design will look like and want to be able to drag and drop a handful of images and text around to different locations and see what they look like on the watch.

However regardless of what layout is used I can't place my widgets where I would like, instead ADS puts them where it wants to put them, which is usually snapped to an outside corner or edge and nowhere near where I dragged/dropped them.

Is there a way of turning off the auto layout mechanism that ADS is using or does widget *have* to be placed within a layout? Surely there must be a way of just manually dragging and dropping a widget anywhere you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does widget have to be placed within a layout?

Either a widget is inside some sort of container or the entire layout resource is a single widget. That is a requirement of XML as much as anything else, as the view hierarchy is embodied in XML layout resource files.

> Surely there must be a way of just manually dragging and dropping a widget anywhere you want it?

Android containers (e.g., `LinearLayout`) embody a set of rules. Your widgets will need to abide by the container's rules. The drag-and-drop operation is attuned to the rules of the standard containers, and the preview will attempt to accurately demonstrate what the result will look like given your choice of widgets and implementation of the rules. Different containers have different rules, and your drag-and-drop description sounds like you are dragging into a `RelativeLayout`, designed to position widgets relative to the boundaries and/or relative to other widgets in the container.